# Combining multidimensional array (ones key with other's values)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Played for hours, but couldn't do this. Task looks very simple, though..I need recursively combine 2 arrays into one. Using first array's values as keys, and second array's leave values as they are. This is what I have:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "First"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Something"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "More"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Nomore"
  }
}
```

Second array

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to achive:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["First"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Something"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["More"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Nomore"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could they have different sizes ? i see in your example first array has 3 items "First", "Something", "First", and the second has the values 1 and 2 only.

Comment: No, they are same size, I copy-pasted incorectly :)

Comment: Awesome, had to make sure first ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using [array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-combine.php)

```
$first_array = array(
  array('first', 'second', 'third'),
  array('more1', 'more2', 'more3'),
);

$second_array = array(
  array('val1', 'val2', 'val3'),
  array('2val1', '2val2', '2val3')
);

$new_array = array();
foreach($first_array AS $k => $v) {
  $new_array[$k] = array_combine($v,$second_array[$k]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$firstArray = array(
  array('first', 'second', 'third'),
  array('more1', 'more2', 'more3'),
);

$secondArray = array(
  array('val1', 'val2', 'val3'),
  array('2val1', '2val2', '2val3')
);

$newArray = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($firstArray); ++$i) {
  $subArray1 = $firstArray[$i];
  $subArray2 = $secondArray[$i];
  $newArray[$i] = array();
  for ($j=0; $j<count($subArray1); ++$j) {
    $key = $subArray1[$j];
    $value = $subArray2[$j];
    $newArray[$i][$key] = $value;
  }
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: Are you sure? My arrays are multidimensional

Comment: @user1876234 updating, give me a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't be more elegant to do something like this ?

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($firstArray as $key => $firstVal)
    foreach ($secondArray as $key => $secondVal)
        array_push($newArray, array_combine($firstVal, $secondVal));
```

This way you'll have the same result you wanted inside `$newArray`
with a bit simpler code.

I haven't tested that though, let me know if it works or breaks :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I was thinking  though if it is possible to achieve same result with foreach, however your code didn't worked; got 4 array keys instead of 2, anyways thanks, I used simplest solution by Johny 5 :)